# selection of the contents of a list

Tags: r

I have statistics treatments to perform on spectroscopic measurements. 
This measures are in the form of RData files gathering several sessions of measurement.
I want after choosing the file, choose the measurement session  (seance1 , seance2, ...)and finally choose the measurement (A1, B1, ...).
Choosing files and session is easy with 'select.list()' but I can't choose the measurement. 
Here is an example :.

```
seance1=list(A1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),B1=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
seance2=list(A2=c(21,21,21,21,21,21,21),B2=c(22,22,22,22,22,22,22),c2=c(23,23,23,23,23,23,23))
save(seance1,seance2,file = "mesure.RData")
rm(list = ls())
fic="mesure.RData"
load(fic,ex<-new.env())
nm=ls.str(ex)
# choix de la seance de mesure
```

How can I choose the measures in the same way than session?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ex$seance1` or `ex$seance2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many ways to access a measurement:

```
get("seance1", envir=ex)$A1
```